# eclipse pdt debugging with xdebug in docker container on linux

Tags: eclipse, xdebug, eclipse-pdt

I have a docker container with apache2, php7 and xdebug configured.

I have run the following script in the container to confirm that xdebug can be remotely triggered from a request url containing ?XDEBUG_START_SESSION=mySession.  When I request a php file with that additional string appended the following script completes showing that the connection was accepted, so it appears that xdebug is being triggered successfully.

```
$address = "127.0.0.1";
$port = 9000;
$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if ($sock === false) {
    echo "Socket connection failed...  ";
    $lastError = socket_last_error();
    echo  socket_strerror($lastError);
} else {
    echo "Socket connection made...  ";
    $bindResult = socket_bind($sock, $address, $port);
    if ($bindResult) {
        echo "Bind was successful...  ";
        $listenResult = socket_listen($sock);
        if ($listenResult) {
            echo "Socket is listening...  ";
            $client = socket_accept($sock);
            if ($client === false) {
                echo "Accept failed...  ";
                $lastError = socket_last_error();
                echo  socket_strerror($lastError);              
            } else {
                echo "Connection accepted...  ";
                echo "connection established: $client";
                socket_close($client);
            }
        } else {
            echo "Listening failed... ";
            $lastError = socket_last_error();
            echo  socket_strerror($lastError);
        }
    } else {
        echo "Bind failed";
        $lastError = socket_last_error();
        echo  socket_strerror($lastError);
    }
    socket_close($sock);
}
```

Now I try to run a manually initiated debug session with eclipse neon.3 and it seems to hang with the status of eclipse showing Launching file.php: (48%)

Any ideas on what to try to get eclipse working with xdebug would be greatly appreciated.

The .ini settings for xdebug are:

```
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 1
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger = 1
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host="172.18.0.1"
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
```

The remote host address was obtained by observing the REMOTE_ADDR entry on phpinfo() of the container.

Comment: you will need in php.in this: `zend_extension_ts="pathTo\php_xdebug.dll"` (for windows) , for Linux will be a `.so` file

Comment: Yes, this line is also in the php.ini file and phpinfo() shows that xdebug is installed.

    zend_extension=/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/xdebug.so

Comment: Did you find a solution for that? Did you find a way to debug your php applications within a container?

Comment: Tarator - Yes, I moved to NetBeans and it worked perfectly.  Java and NetBeans installed on base computer with docker container for apache webserver and php.  Good luck.